# Deferred Rendering with SFML

Tags: opengl, sfml

I've been looking to implement a deferred rendering system in SFML.

I've read the tutorials on [OGLdev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html) for it, and I was wondering how to draw a scene built in SFML (sprites, text, etc) to the multiple render targets needed for the deferred shading process.

Basically, I need to be able to get SFML to draw every object to the GBuffer's MRTs, so I can have the parameters needed to do what I want.

Is this possible, or will I have to build my own rendering backend from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you could try using only SFML is to use a sf::RenderTexture. It allows you to render sf::Drawables offscreen.

So you could define multiple RenderTexture and mix them together before rendering on screen.

Be aware that by directly using SFML you cannot achieve 3D rendering.

Here's a link to the documentation : http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3-fr/classsf_1_1RenderTexture.php

EDIT: 
Since I can't comment, here is my suggestion. You create 3 (or more) RenderTextures to hold the informations about the positions, the colors and the normals of your final image. You can then pass these textures to a shader computing your final image by using the informations stored in your textures. I have no clues about the performance of this approach since I never tried it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using RT's before, but now I understand the process a bit better, so I might try it!

I'm developing a 2D game, so that won't be an issue.

Also, how would you "mix" the textures? Are you saying that I use one RT for each texture (position, diffuse, and normal), too?